# Application Status Bar Updates

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF line of business application. When a click a menu item I want to update the status bar with the status before the code is executed and after. For example, on clicking the button to navigate from View A to View B the status would update to "Navigating to View A...", the view would change and then the status would be updated to "...now at View A".

This might look something like:

```
status = "Navigating to View A...";
doTheNavigation();
status = "...now at View A";
```

When I run this, the status doesn't actually update on the UI until the method has completed and therefore the user has missed the first status update.

Some of the code executing will be a call to a database to do something, get some data and so could be a "lengthy" operation (although usually completes in <1 sec).

Does anyone have any alternative ideas to me changing all of the "lengthy" operations to execute on background worker threads? or is this **the** solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, it might help: [Label text not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921612/label-text-not-updated)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a toast notification instead of status bar notification, since you just want to inform the user briefly that you are 'going to do something now' and you don't want that msg to be in the status bar notifications area (for a long time...)