# ListView wont update

Tags: c#, winforms

We've made an Application with a MainWindow called MV.

When main starts it launches our StartProgram method as a BackgroundWorker and the Application.Run(MW);

```
MainWindow MW = new MainWindow();
BackgroundWorker.DoWork += (obj, e) => StartProgram(MW);
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
Application.Run(MW);
```

In StartProgram we create instances of Patient, which we want to show in our listView1.
We do this by calling this method, which is in MW:

```
public void SetListSource(Patient p)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("woohoo");
    item.SubItems.Add("a");
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**StartProgram stalls when it reaches listView1.Items.Add(item);**

Our guess is, that it waits for MW (MainWindow), but we can't figure out how to fix it.
We have a button in MW, that does somethis similar, except it only sends "1" and "a" to the listView1.

```
private void Sort_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("1");
    item.SubItems.Add("a");
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Does anybody know how to make SetListSource(...) work as Sort_Button_Click(...)?

**EDIT**
Solved with Invoke

Comment: You're crossing threads from a background thread into the UI thread. You'll probably want to `Invoke` on that.

Comment: Thanks a million, Lloyd! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't modify your GUI directly from another thread**. You need to use a delegate and invoke your control. In your thread you have to do:

```
CONTROL.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
  CONTROL.Items.Add(item);
}
));
```

Source:

[BackgroundWorker multithread access to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183287/backgroundworker-multithread-access-to-form)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `Invoke`, but that's probably unnecessary. You can use `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event instead:

```
BackgroundWorker.DoWork += 
  (s, e) => 
  {
    e.Result = DoAllTheComplicatedWork();
  }
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
  (s, e) =>
  {
    // Back on the UI thread, we can do whatever we want
    listView1.Items.Add(((SomeDTO)e.Result).Patient);
  }
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Or, you can do the whole thing using `await`:

```
MW.Load += async (s, e)
  {
    var result = await Task.Run(() => SomeCPUWork());
    listView1.Items.Add(((SomeDTO)e.Result).Patient);
  }
```

The key point is, you really want a separation between the UI and whatever you need to do in background. I definitely wouldn't pass a form (or any other control) to any method that's supposed to be executed on a different thread.