# Checking if any key pressed in console application C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I need to check if any key is pressed in a console application. The key can be any key in the keyboard. Something like:

```
if(keypressed)
{ 

//Cleanup the resources used

}
```

I had come up with this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
cki=Console.ReadKey();

if(cki.Equals(cki))
Console.WriteLine("key pressed");
```

It works well with all keys except modifier keys - how can I check these keys?

Comment: ConsoleKeyInfo cki; cki=Console.ReadKey();

if(cki.Equals(cki)) Console.WriteLine("key pressed");

Works well with all keys except Modifier keys.

Comment: Wow you have changed your question a lot since I answered it..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can help you:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
do {
    while (! Console.KeyAvailable) {
        // Do something
   }       
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

If you want to use it in an `if`, you can try this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
while (true)
{
   cki = Console.ReadKey();
   if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
     break;
}
```

For any key is very simple: remove the `if`.

---

As [@DawidFerenczy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971141/dawid-ferenczy) mentioned we have to note that `Console.ReadKey()` is blocking. It stops the execution and waits until a key is pressed. Depending on the context, this may (not) be handy.

If you need to not block the execution, just test `Console.KeyAvailable`. It will contain `true` if a key was pressed, otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the [`Console.KeyAvailible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable.aspx) if you want nonblocking.

```
do {
    Console.WriteLine("\nPress a key to display; press the 'x' key to quit.");

// Your code could perform some useful task in the following loop. However, 
// for the sake of this example we'll merely pause for a quarter second.

    while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
        Thread.Sleep(250); // Loop until input is entered.
    cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed the '{0}' key.", cki.Key);
    } while(cki.Key != ConsoleKey.X);
}
```

If you want blocking then use `Console.ReadKey`.

Comment: Is it possible to use like if(cki.key==ConsoleKey.Enter). instead of specifying ConsoleKey.Enter, checking for all keys at once bcoz i need to avoid while loop